# How to prepend a character to every line of the body of a git commit

Tags: git, git-log

Our code review tool uses Markdown for the CR description. I want to automate
writing these descriptions by taking information from the git commits being
reviewed.

Say I have a git commit with the following subject and body:

```
This is the subject line

This is a long paragraph spanning multiple lines wrapped to 80
characters. 

This is a second paragraph.
```

I want to create a git log formatter that produces the following output from
this commit:

```
`<commit short hash>` - This is the subject line

> This is a long paragraph spanning multiple lines wrapped to 80
> characters.
> 
> This is a second paragraph.
```

I have tried the following command to produce this output but I can not find a
way to prepend the `>` to every line of the body

```
$ git log --format='`%h` - %s%n%n> %b%n' 'HEAD^..HEAD'
`e8aa4cf` - This is the subject line

> This is a long paragraph spanning multiple lines wrapped to 80
characters.

This is a second paragraph.
```

Another option I tried was to use `w(80,2,2)` to pad the body but this is
also missing the `>` on each line.

```
$ git log --format='`%h` - %s%n%n>%w(80,2,2)%b%n' 'HEAD^..HEAD'
`e8aa4cf` - This is the subject line

>  This is a long paragraph spanning multiple lines wrapped to 80 characters.

  This is a second paragraph.
```

Can this be done using `git log --format='X'`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `git log --format` doesn't allow to change the body text.

As an alternative `sed` could be used to insert the padding `>`, like:

```
git log --pretty=format:'`%h` - %s%n%w(80,8,2)%b' | sed 's/^        /> /' | sed -z 's/\n\n>/\n>\n>/g'
```